# setOnClickListener doesn't work for Image Slider in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, androidimageslider

I have been trying to set a click listener for `com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider` but it doesn't work.
The image slider works perfect, it shows the slideshow. The only issue is that it doesn't get clicked.

Following the XML code of the image slider.

```
            <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
                android:id="@+id/image_slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/item_dashboard_image_height"
                app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
                app:iss_corner_radius="5"
                app:iss_delay="0"
                app:iss_error_image="@color/colorDarkGrey"
                app:iss_period="2500"
                app:iss_placeholder="@color/colorDarkGrey"
                app:iss_selected_dot="@drawable/default_selected_dot"
                app:iss_unselected_dot="@drawable/default_unselected_dot"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Following is the Kotlin code. This is within my onCreate() method. It doesn't show the toast message. Where is the mistake?

```
    class DetailsActivity : BaseActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            binding = ActivityProductDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
            binding.imageSlider.setOnClickListener {
    
                Toast.makeText(this,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the complete code of your fragment/activity where this is happening?

Comment: Question updated, please check. I have more lines of codes in the `DetailsActivity.kt` and within the `onCreate()` method. Code within the `onCreate` doesn't have any impact on it, I have removed those codes (in the onCreate) and checked if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I used the `clickListener` in the `onCreate()`. The solution is that I have to use the `ClickListener` after binding the data rather than using it in the `onCreate()` method. It's now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must add in your imageSlider  setItemOnClickListener method.
Add this code in your onCreate
imageSlide.setItemOnClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

This gave me a problem for a while. My concern was a click listener on the image slider (not a specific image). I worked around it by setting up a transparent button appear on top of the image slider using CoordinatorLayout.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp">

                    <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
                        app:iss_period="3300"
                        app:iss_delay="0"
                        android:id="@+id/image_slider"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:id="@+id/button_trans"/>
                </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then i set up an onclick listener for the button.